# System.Web.Services.WebService - Is it possible to isolate the service per client

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, asmx

I have an legacy System.Web.Services.WebService (not WCF) that I have to maintain.

Ocassionly I run into some wired behaviours that I would describe as race conditions.

- Either the service hangs and has to be restarted.
- Sometimes I get this exception:

  ```
  System.NotSupportedException: Multiple simultaneous connections
  or connections with different connection strings inside the same 
  transaction are not currently supported.
      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
      ...
  ```

I know whats the root cause. The service utilizes a lib that talks to mysql and was not designed with webservices in mind. Unfortunatly I cannot change this lib.

One example webmethod looks like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void DoSomething()
{
    var login = this.Session["login"] as LoginDetails;
    ExternalLib.SetLoginData(login.Schema, login.User, login.Pass);

    ExternalLib.PerformTask();

}
```

So the problem here is this:

- `ExternalLib.SetLoginData` just set's some global vars
- `ExternalLib.PerformTask` performs database calls, some inside a transaction.
- The process is like `1. Create MySqlConnection or take it from cache 2. Create MySqlCommand 3. Execute Command 4. Dispose command`

Client a) calls `DoSomething()` and I init his connection. Half way done with his job Client b) calls `DoSomething()` which apparently changes the Login-Data for client a and the next call inside the transaction will use the login from client b) which causes the transaction.

Anyway, I know this is a bad design but my question is how to workaround this.
Currently (since I only have 10 clients) I created a dedicated Website on a differnet port which all point to the same root directory but this is an akward solution.

Maybe there is a possibility to run every session inside its on realm. Any suggestions. If I understand this page correctly for WCF is is the default behaviour: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

> Per-Call Services
>   Per-call services are the Windows Communication
>   Foundation default instantiation mode. When the service type is
>   configured for per-call activation, a service instance, a common
>   language runtime (CLR) object, exists only while a client call is in
>   progress. Every client request gets a new dedicated service instance.

Comment: If you must preserve the code then wrapping it might not be a bad plan. It is not scalable, but for 10 clients I don't see a problem if the queries don't take 10 minutes per.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as this is probably a threading issue you can lock the `ExternalLib` to prevent separate instances from calling the code.

```
public class ExtenalLibWrapper
{
    private static object Locker = new object();

    public void DoSomething(LoginDetails details)
    {
        lock(Locker)
        {
            ExternalLib.SetLoginData(login.Schema, login.User, login.pass);
            ExternalLib.PerformTask();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought about this, too. But actually multiple WebMethods use the external lib, so I would need a global lock which would virtually change my werbservice into a `one request at a time` service.

Comment: Well you can move all the external lib logic into the wrapper to handle the global locking. You might be able to create several other services with the `ExeternalLib` logic that you can proxy the calls to to mimic multiple requests. Honestly you're limited by the `ExternalLib` since it can only handle one request at a time. What you're doing right now is probably close you what you'll end up with.

Comment: And what about WCF? Is this correct that WCF does the isolation for me? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx   In that case I could make my `legacy` webservice call a Wcf Service.

Comment: It might. You'll have to test that out since I'm not a WCF expert.

Comment: Well, I used semaphores, but now my webservice uses global locking.

Comment: Yeah you can use multiple processes instead of multiple threads. It has more overhead, but it works. You can separate out the legacy code and use named pipes to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

I already wrapped all my public methods in a neat execute wrapper to provide global exception logging.

This forces my webservice to process one request after another, but like I mentioned, the max. number of simultanious clients is 10

```
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static int Add(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return Execute(() =>
        {
            var calculator = new Calculator();
            return calculator.Add(value1, value2);
        });
    }

    private static Logger logger =
        LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyService).Name);
    private static System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim ss =
        new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    private void Execute(Action method)
    {
        ss.Wait();
        try { method.Invoke(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.FatalException(method.Method + " failed", ex); throw; 
        }
        finally { ss.Release(); }
    }

    private T Execute<T>(Func<T> method)
    {
        ss.Wait();
        try { return method.Invoke(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.FatalException(method.Method + " failed", ex); throw; 
        }
        finally
        {
            ss.Release();
        }
    }
}
```